# Polymorpic paperclip working strange with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

**view:**

```
<div class="kitchen_settings">
<%= form_for @kitchen, :html => { :multipart => true, "data-ajax" => false} do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_field :title,placeholder: "#{current_user.fullname}'s Kitchen", autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.text_field :bio, placeholder: 'something about your kitchen' %>

    <%= f.fields_for :picture do |photo| %>
        <%= photo.file_field :avatar %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**kitchen_controller.rb**

```
class KitchensController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new
        @kitchen = Kitchen.new
        @kitchen.build_picture
    end

    def create
        @kitchen = current_user.build_kitchen(kitchen_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @kitchen.save
          format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'Kitchen was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: dashboard_path }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @kitchen.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    def show
        @kitchen = Kitchen.find (params[:id])
    end

    private
    def kitchen_params
        params.require(:kitchen).permit(:title,:bio, picture_attributes: [:avatar])
    end
end
```

**kitchen.rb**

```
class Kitchen < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_one :picture, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :picture
end
```

**picture.rb**

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

    has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100"}, default_url: "/assets/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment :avatar, :presence => true,
    :content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] },
    :size => { :in => 0..500.kilobytes }
end
```

[And its giving me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBs2V.png)

I wanted polymorphic picture model. I decided to deal with polymorphic picture association but its just rollbacks always... Stuck. I've attached the image from the console. Thanks!!
[Debugged it using binding.pry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFMf3.png)

Comment: do you know why the ROLLBACK is happening?

Comment: Could you do a log of `kitchen` object before `kitchen.save` method. Try capturing user and picture association as well. It might help us understand . Try logging `@kitchen.errors` as well

Comment: @emaillenin its not giving me any error. Cant figure it out.

Comment: @Surya Yes, i did it and have attached the debugged image. Have a look please...

Comment: The issue I see here is that your image file size is exceeding than what's mentioned for validation limit. Try uploading an image size b/w 0-500 kb.

Comment: @Surya I did try uploading image with 28kb but it didnt work!
It gives me @messages={:"picture.imageable"=>["must exist"]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 5, whenever we define a belongs_to association, it is required to have the associated record present by default after this change.To change this behavior i managed to do it this way:

**picture.rb**

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true, optional: true

    has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100"}, default_url: "/assets/:style/missing.png"

  validates_attachment :avatar, :presence => true,
    :content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] },
    :size => { :in => 0..500.kilobytes }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with you validation of `imageable` in `image.rb`

When you store kitchen alongwith image in single go. `Imageable` validation is failed for image as kitchen is not created yet. That's why it's rollback.

To confirm it you can remove the validation temporarily.

You need to use `inverse_of` to make this work

in **image.rb**

```
belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true , inverse_of: :image
```

in **kitchen.rb**

```
has_one :picture, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy,inverse_of: :imageable
```

I added **inverse_of** in both the associations. It tells rails that these  associations are inverse to each other so if any of it's set then don't make a query to fetch the other.

In this way if you set any association then other will be set automatically and validation won't fail.

[Here](https://rossta.net/blog/use-inverse_of.html) is a nice blog for inverse_of usage.

Comment: Thanks. But it didnt work. It just rollbacks every time!

Comment: On debugging it gave same error as before
[paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/6df73ba57a8324b794a7d1bb15d4e20020170214-3686-tdt3cn.png to /tmp/6df73ba57a8324b794a7d1bb15d4e20020170214-3686-h0065s.png
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/6df73ba57a8324b794a7d1bb15d4e20020170214-3686-h0065s.png'
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false